# Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to add an XML `attrs` attribute that contains a `<` character:

```
<field name="discovery_note2" nolabel="1" placeholder="Note 2"
       attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('is_discovery', '=', False), ('note_amount', '<', 0)]}"/>
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error: XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values,

How can I pass the condition, if the `note_amount` field value is less than zero, then it should be invisible.

Note: `note_amount` is a computed field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape `<` as `&lt;` in XML because an unescaped `<` is expected to be the start of markup.

See also [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/290085)